# Difference between render buffer attachment and texture attachment

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer

We can depth and color attachment for texture object and render buffer object, what is the difference between two?

Comment: One of them can be sampled as a texture in a shader, and the other one can only be blitted into another framebuffer (assuming you want to  see the end result). Sometimes you do not need to see the end result (e.g. you need a depth buffer, but you do not actually need to be able to read the contents of the depth buffer for your algorithm) so a renderbuffer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know is so late to answer, but I was searching the same doubt and I've seen your post.
The difference between them is that a texture allow upload and read pixels from c++ program (CPU). The render buffers are always in the GPU.